# DRY ReactJS components - Avoid implementing CRUD for each component in one app

Tags: node.js, reactjs

Well, actually I'm working on developing a web app using ReactJS. This app includes several components; each has its own attributes defined in the state. In addition, each has its own CRUD components. E.g. I have `Posts` component, which has `PostsList`, `NewPost`, `UpdatePost`, `PostInfo` components. Also I have `Users` component, which includes `UsersList`, `NewUser`, `UpdateUser`, `UserInfo` components, and so on.

What has been noticed that, every time I have to repeat the same steps for each component (`Posts` and `Users`), and the only different things are: the state attributes' names & types, and the APIs that manipulate the data.

So, how can I clean my code to keep it DRY as possible??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by `I have to repeat the same steps for each component `?

Comment: This depends on your code. And with the code this may be a question for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ and not SO. If you don't use state management lib (Redux), it could possibly improve the situation.

Comment: @lomse I mean: for Posts component, it will have sub-components; PostsList, NewPost, UpdatePost, PostInfo. For each, I have to write a code for functions: render, fetch, manipulate data, etc.
And for Users components, I have to do the same exactly, but with different attributes names and types.

Comment: can you share your code?